# Should I keep dismembering people?

Tags: nioh

In Nioh, after an enemy dies, but before they fall to the ground and lose their physics, you are able to keep hitting them, which will lop off their limbs. Usually this is just the head and arms, but I *believe* it's possible to cut people in half, as well.

Is there any benefit (or penalty) for doing this? It's hard to tell if there are extra drops or anything, because there's an obscene shower of blood and sparkles whenever enemies die (even more so when you dismember them).

Comment: A benefit (for me), is simple satisfaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dismemberment has no actual gameplay benefits or penalties, it's simply aesthetic. It's [not even present in the japanese version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VH7kIp_tydo) of the game.